# FailureHandler and SuccessHandler both triggering from google.script.run

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

In the example below, both my failure handler and my success handler are triggering in the verifyPW function of the html file.  According to the .gs, I pass a "true" statement when I want a success and throw an error when I want a failure.  It seems to work for the cacheMeOutside() function, but not the verifyPW function.

code.gs

```
function verifyPassword(pwd) {
  var password = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("userPassword");
  if (pwd === password) {
    CacheService.getUserCache().put('userPassword', pwd, 600);
    return true;
  }
  else {
    throw new Error("Incorrect Password");
  }
}

function checkPassword(){
  var userPW = CacheService.getUserCache().get('userPassword');
  var password = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("userPassword");
  if (userPW === password){
    return true;
  }
  else {
    throw new Error("Password Unavailable");
  }
}

function getAddr() {
  var addr = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('PortalAddr');
  return addr;
}
```

page.html

```
function prompt2(message, title) {

    title = (title == undefined) ? "The page says:" : title;

    var div = $('<div id="jPrompt">');
    var brk = $('<br>');
    var input = $('<input type="password" id="pw">');
    div.html(message);
    div.attr('title', title);
    div.append(brk);
    div.append(input)
    div.dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        modal: true,
        height: 'auto',
        width: 'auto',
        draggable: true,
        resizable: false,
        position: ['center',200],
        buttons: [{
            text: "Submit",
            click: function () {
                  verifyPW();
                  $(this).dialog("close");
                  div.remove();
            }
        }]
    });
}

function alert2(message, title) {

    title = (title == undefined) ? "The page says:" : title;

    var div = $('<div id="jPrompt">');
    div.html(message);
    div.attr('title', title);
    div.dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        modal: true,
        height: 'auto',
        width: 'auto',
        draggable: true,
        resizable: false,
        position: ['center',200],
        buttons: [{
            text: "Close",
            click: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                div.remove();
            }
        }]
    });
}

function cacheMeOutside(){
google.script.run.withFailureHandler(prompt2('Please enter your password:','Password')).withSuccessHandler(getAddress).checkPassword();
}

function verifyPW() {
var pwd = document.getElementById("pw").value;
google.script.run.withFailureHandler(alert2("Password is incorrect.  Please try again.","Error")).withSuccessHandler(getAddress).verifyPassword(pwd);
}
//alert2 is just another jquery dialog like prompt2

function getAddress() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(openSesame).getAddr();
  }

function openSesame(addr) {
  window.open(addr,'_top');
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] (apparently the code from page.html isn't complete, and the gs code doesn't include the HMTL Service call)

Comment: Can you provide more details, beyond "it doesn't work"? Are you getting any error? What behaviour are you expecting? What are you experiencing instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass a function to `.withFailureHandler()`. You're passing a void/null as that is the return from evaluating your `alert()`. Changee to:

```
.withFailureHandler(() => alert2("Password is incorrect.  Please try again."))
```

Comment: That worked perfect!  Could you please explain why this happens?  alert2 and prompt2 are both functions in themselves, as they're jquery dialogs that act as alert() and prompt().  I don't fully understand how wrapping a function in another function fixes this and I'd like to know more.  You say that it returns a void/null after evaluating the alert2, but why is it evaluating the alert2?  Shouldn't it take the result of the client-side function (success/exception) and run whatever function is attached to the success/failure handler respectively?  Thank you!

Comment: @NMALM `alert` is a function. `alert()` returns `null/void` after executing the function. `alert()` is not a function. `alert()` is `null`. `()=>alert()` is a function. Get it?

Comment: the alert I'm using isn't a standard alert, it is a function to call a jquery dialog.  I have added the alert2 function to the code above.  I guess what I don't understand is why the returned value of the function in the failurehandler matters?  Shouldn't only the first function results matter and trigger the success or failure handler based on that?

Comment: @NMALM `alert2` is a function. `alert2()` returns `null/void` after executing the function. `alert2()` is not a function. `alert2()` is `null`. `()=>alert2()` is a function. Get it?

Comment: @NMALM `typeof alert2 ===
'function'`.`typeof alert2() ===
'undefined'`

Comment: @NMALM *what I don't understand is why the returned value of the function in the failurehandler matters? Shouldn't only the first function results matter and trigger the success or failure handler based on that?* You're not passing a function to failureHandler, You're passing the returned value of another function to failureHandler. The another function executes before the server function is even triggered.